# Mongoose findById() callbacks only return for nonsense data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am running Mongoose, I have a working connection, and [findById()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) is returning results, sometimes:

**Case 1: Nonsense Query**

```
models.Repo.findById("somefakeid", function(err, result){console.log('woo')})
```

Result: prints 'woo'

**Case 2: Actual Query**

However callbacks don't run for actual, non-nonsense data queries:

```
models.Repo.findById("5229ea37cb1d6bd4b153f213", function(err, result){console.log('woo')})
```

Result: does not ever run the callback.

Why does the actual query never run the callback?

Comment: You're probably going to find that the first one never hits the db, since mongoose can't get an id out of that string.  The second one does hit the db, though, so the problem is with either the db or your connection to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@aarondufour is correct about Case 1. Mongoose is going to attempt to cast that string to an ID, which will throw an exception before ever needing to issue a database command to mongodb, thus the callback will be invoked with an error whether the DB is connected or not.

For case 2, almost certainly mongoose is queueing the command because you don't have a working connection to mongodb yet. You may think you do, but the "my callback never runs" symptom is caused by mongoose queueing commands 99 out of 100 times, so investigate the problem assuming that is the case first before chasing weird edge cases.